# Скрипт не открывается в EXE формате

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe

```
import bs4
import time
from selenium import webdriver  # pip install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager  # pip install webdriver-manager


with webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())) as driver:  # Открываем хром
    driver.get("https://bankiros.ru/currency/cbrf")  # Открываем страницу
    time.sleep(5)  # Время на прогрузку страницы
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    stumm = soup.find("tbody")
    names = stumm.find_all('tr', class_='currency')
    for i in names:
        head = i.text
        print(head)
input()
```

Перевел этот скрипт в EXE расширение. При запуске сразу же пропадает, хотя из консоли вполне работает. Не подскажете почему?

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать переустановить все библиотеки и заново скомпилировать ваш скрипт используя библиотеку PyInstaller

Comment: Для копмилирования я использую инструмент AUTO-PY-TO-EXE, пар еры разработанные на основе BeautifulSoup, успешно компилируются, при использовании библиотеки Selenium почему-то не срабатывает.